# How to solve this problem with Dirac Delta function?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I am struggling to solve this problem:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (t^2+\cos (\pi t))\delta(t-1) dt $$
in System and Signals. I saw a [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBM3B.png) in the internet. Is it solved by this formula?

Comment: Please type up your question instead of asking people to follow links.  They cannot be searched and can rot.

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating a function $f(t)$ against the delta function $t \mapsto \delta(t-1)$ corresponds to evaluating $f(1)$. In our case, this is $1^2 + \cos \pi 1 = 0$. If this seems strange or magical to you, that's good. There's a lot of subterfuge and sophistication involved here.